# Lm_sensors not reading gfx card temperature right

Tags: radeon, temperature, sensors

I have ran sensors-detect and lm_sensors still returns the following.

```
radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +511.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +47.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +46.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +47.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Comment: This would not be so bad if the device was measuring in imperial units and the software was expecting metric.. ;-)  How did you run lm_sensors? Is that an option for sensors-detect?

Comment: lm_sensors is the package. It's run by typing "sensors"

Answer (score 0):

You need to installed the latest amd drivers for your video card:

```
apt install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```